# My app passed windows app certification test with warnings,will I be able to publish it on the windows store

Tags: desktop-application, windows-store

My app passed the test with four warnings.For one of these warnings it was written in report that "You can safely ignore the unsigned DLL, .OCX, .SCR, .CPL or .EXE files listed here that are not one of the app’s main executable, or a driver."
So that takes the count to three.
So, will I be able to publish my app successfully to windows store without fixing these warnings.The full report is shown below:

Clean reversible install test

WARNING
Remove all non-shared files and folders
Warning: The non-shared files and folders test detected the following errors:
File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\CMiC\CMiC ECM Explorer\CMiC ECM.InstallState' was not deleted.
Impact if not fixed: A user might remove an app to free up disk space or to return the computer to the state before installing the app. The uninstall process must restore the machine to its original state for the best user experience.
How to fix: Remove all the files and Add/Remove Program entries. See link below for more information:
Installer Properties

PASSED
Do not force an immediate reboot during installation

PASSED
Do not force an immediate reboot during uninstallation

WARNING
Write appropriate Add/Remove Program values
Warning: The registry population test detected the following error: app didn’t create the required registry entries.
An optional value 'InstallLocation' is missing or invalid for program CMiC ECM Explorer.
Impact if not fixed: Apps must create these registry entries DisplayName, InstallLocation, Publisher, UninstallString and ProductVersion. Apps that don’t create the required registry entries may not be found by enterprise inventory tools. This can cause problems with OS migrations and upgrades, and Windows telemetry tools may not accurately report info about the app.
How to fix: Add the necessary info to the app’s Windows Installer package so it can configure Add/Remove Programs in Control Panel correctly. Setting these properties automatically writes the corresponding values into the registry. See link below for more information: 
Configuring Add/Remove Programs

PASSED
Single user registry check

Install to the correct folders test

WARNING
Install to Program Files
Warning: The install to Program Files test detected the following errors:
Program CMiC ECM Explorer fails due to missing install location.
Impact if not fixed: Native apps e.g. 32 and 64 bit must be installed to the %ProgramFiles% folder by default, note that 32 bit apps installing on x64 versions of Windows must be stored under %ProgramFiles(x86)%. Storing program files in another folder can cause access and security problems for the user.
How to fix: Write the files to the correct folders. See link below for more information: 
Working with Known Folders

PASSED
Write to the %WINDIR% or %SystemDrive%

Digitally signed file test

WARNING
Install signed driver and executable files
All unsigned files of the following extensions: EXEs, DLLs, SYS, DRV, OCX, SCR, and CPL will be reported.
Warning: The file, driver signing test detected the following errors:
Non-driver file C:\Program Files (x86)\CMiC\CMiC ECM Explorer\wkhtmltopdf.exe does not have a valid signature, either embedded or via a catalog file.
Non-driver file C:\Program Files (x86)\CMiC\CMiC ECM Explorer\CMiC ECM.exe does not have a valid signature, either embedded or via a catalog file.
Non-driver file C:\Program Files (x86)\CMiC\CMiC ECM Explorer\UsrCtrl.dll does not have a valid signature, either embedded or via a catalog file.
Non-driver file C:\Program Files (x86)\CMiC\CMiC ECM Explorer\ssleay32.dll does not have a valid signature, either embedded or via a catalog file.
Non-driver file C:\Program Files (x86)\CMiC\CMiC ECM Explorer\OutlookGridControl.dll does not have a valid signature, either embedded or via a catalog file.
Non-driver file C:\Program Files (x86)\CMiC\CMiC ECM Explorer\libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll does not have a valid signature, either embedded or via a catalog file.
Non-driver file C:\Program Files (x86)\CMiC\CMiC ECM Explorer\libeay32.dll does not have a valid signature, either embedded or via a catalog file.
Application main installer file C:\Users\vakul.kataria\Desktop\CMiC ECM Explorer Release(29-May-2015)\CMiC_ECM_Explorer(3.0.0)\CMiC ECM Explorer.msi does not have a valid signature, either embedded or via a catalog file.
If any of the above files are DLLs, OCX, SCR, CPL or EXEs that are not one of the application’s main executables (has a shortcut on start menu or desktop), they can safely be ignored. All others need to be signed to meet the Windows App Certification requirements.
Impact if not fixed: Having digitally signed files allows users to know that software is genuine. It makes it possible to detect that a file has been tampered with, such as by a virus. Windows has the ability to prevent any unsigned app from launching with administrator access. Sign the app if you want it to operate correctly in locked-down environments without popup or UAC messages.
How to fix: You can safely ignore the unsigned DLL, .OCX, .SCR, .CPL or .EXE files listed here that are not one of the app’s main executable, or a driver. All files except drivers must be Authenticode signed, drivers must be WHQL certified. See link below for more information: 
Digital Signatures for Kernel Modules on Windows

Support x64 Windows test

PASSED
Install platform specific files, and drivers

OS version checking test

PASSED
Proper OS version checking

User account control (UAC) test

PASSED
User account control run level

Adhere to system restart manager messages

PASSED
Don't block reboot

Safe mode test

PASSED
Do not load services and drivers in safe mode

Comment: no one's gonna read this question. summarize it or ask properly..! for guidance go through this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

As explained in ["Using the Windows App Certification Kit"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27414):

> **Passed with warnings** denotes the app has passed overall, but one or more requirements passed with warnings.  Although this overall score will not cause the app to be rejected during onboarding, we strongly recommend that you investigate and address all warnings.

Based on that, you should be get certified for the Windows Logo, although as @Peter Torr explains, publishing to the Windows Store isn't available yet.

Comment: But not to the store. You can self-distribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can't publish desktop apps on the Windows Store yet -- it was announced at //Build 2015, but there is no date yet for when submissions will start.